# Jquery additions debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot seem to figure out where I went wrong with this.

favorite
share [g+] share [fb] share [tw]

I'm creating a website as a small store for personal use, my main question here is how would I code a function for the additon of all of it?

six single check boxes for various types of peripheral devices including printer, monitors, modems or other devices with which you are familiar. Assume the basic computer system price of $500.00 and then add appropriate prices based on user checks.
Monitor 299.99 Printer 129.99 Speakers 49.99 CDRW 159.99 Scanner 129.99 Modem 49.99

If I add just a scanner, my total will be $629.99. If I add a modem and a monitor, my total will be $849.98.

I may be overlooking something simple. When I click a checkbox, it does not add to the total like it's supposed to.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Problem 9</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  function calculateCost() {
    var ret = 500;
    var $selected = $('input:checked', $peripherals);

    $selected.each(function() {
      ret += parseFloat($(this).attr('alt'));
    });

    return ret.toFixed(2);
  }

  function setCost() {
    $total.text(calculateCost());
  }

  var $peripherals = $('#peripherals');
  var $total = $('#total');
  $('input[type="checkbox"]', $peripherals).on('change', setCost);

  setCost();

});

</script>
<body>
<h1>What peripherals do you want to add?</h1>
<form id="peripherals">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" value="Monitor" alt="299.99">Monitor<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Printer" value="Printer" alt="129.99">Printer<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Speakers" value="Speakers" alt="49.99">Speakers<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CDRW" value="CDRW" alt="159.99">CDRW<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Scanner" value="Scanner" alt="129.99">Scanner<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Modem" value="Modem" alt="49.99">Modem<br>
</form>
<p>Total cost:<span id="total">0</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please give your questions a specific title that describes the problem or topic. "Cannot figure out what I've done wrong" describes at least 50% of the questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This looks like it's basically doing as you describe.  http://jsfiddle.net/RGkXY/

Comment: Yes, but for some reason it's not working and I cannot debug or find out why.

Comment: @user1203482 You need to tell us what specifically isn't working.  Testing in jsfiddle, it looks absolutely fine.

Comment: When I click a checkbox, it does not add to the total like it's supposed to.

Comment: The fiddle works because the library is added automatically. Change it so no library is included and nothing runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the JavaScript console, I bet it would have an error about `$` not being defined. It is because you are not linking to the jQuery js file correctly.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

It is looking for it on your domain, not jQuery's

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

notice that I added the `//`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5sTv/1/)

If you are running this off the file system and not a server, you need to add `http://`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

So it will use the right protocol to fetch the file or just download the file and link to it locally.

Comment: Didn't fix it for me.
<html>
<head>
<title>Problem 9</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Works for me, are you cached? Clear your cache.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the complete code? All of it? Maybe I missed something. cleared my cache, no dice.

Comment: Are you running this off of the file system and not a server?

Comment: Yes, running it off a flash drive.

Comment: Edited my question with the running example and how you probably need to fix it since you are probably running it off your file system.